# discord.js member find by displayname return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't figure out why i can't find a member of a discord server by their displayname. When I try it returns undefined but all variables're correct.
Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
    let guilds = client.guilds.cache.get(guilda);
    setInterval(() =>{
    getChange(function(result){
      result.forEach(risultato => {
        if(!(guilds.channels.cache.some((channel) => channel.name === "ticket-"+risultato))){
          getNames(risultato, function(results){
          let names = guilds.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === results);
          // results is equals to my displayname ex "H3r0HD_";
          // guilds is the correct guild id
          // but names return undefined
          console.log(names+" "+guilds+ " "+ results);
          cChannel(name, guilds, risultato);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }, 5000);
}

exports.getNames = function(ticket, callback){
    connection.query("SELECT id_utente FROM `ticket` WHERE id_ticket = '" + ticket + "' AND id_stato = 'open'", function (err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        return (callback(result[0].id_utente));
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your `getNames` function look like?

Comment: Ensure you have the intents for getting all members. Whilst this isn't required *yet*, it'd still be a good idea to do.